# JSON structure only considering last row in array

Tags: php, sql

I have the following table:

[image]

I am trying to create a JSON structure from this table as follows:

```
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "pi_id": 0,
        "rcv_counter": 6,
        "rcv_RSSI": -64,
        "rcv_snr": 5.75,
        "packet_length": 125,
        "tag_id": 1,
        "cmd_id": 0,
        "tx_count": 226,
        "created_at": "2021-04-08 17:40:00",
        "measurement": {
            "voltage": 222,
            "acceleration": "3820"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "pi_id": 0,
        "rcv_counter": 144,
        "rcv_RSSI": -64,
        "rcv_snr": 6.25,
        "packet_length": 131,
        "tag_id": 1,
        "cmd_id": 1,
        "tx_count": 108,
        "created_at": "2021-04-08 17:45:00",
        "measurement": {
            "voltage": 222,
            "acceleration": 3916
            "location": "47.649755"
        }
     }
```

This is my current code attempt to get an output:

```
while ($resulthead = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       
            $output[$resulthead['id']] = [
                'id' => $resulthead["id"],
                'pi_id' => $resulthead["pi_id"],
                'rcv_counter' => $resulthead["rcv_counter"],
                'rcv_RSSI' => $resulthead["rcv_RSSI"],
                'rcv_snr' => $resulthead["rcv_snr"],
                'packet_length' => $resulthead["packet_length"],
                'tag_id' => $resulthead["tag_id"],
                'cmd_id' => $resulthead["cmd_id"],
                'tx_count' => $resulthead["tx_count"],
                'created_at' => $resulthead['created_at'] 
            ];
          
                switch ($resulthead['measurement_type']) {
                    case 0:
                        $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['voltage'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['acceleration'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['location'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                        break; 
                } 
    }
```

For some reason this code only considers the last `measurement_type` per `id` and ignore the previous ones. My output looks as follows:

```
"1": {
        "id": 1,
        "pi_id": 0,
        "rcv_counter": 6,
        "rcv_RSSI": -64,
        "rcv_snr": 5.75,
        "packet_length": 125,
        "tag_id": 1,
        "cmd_id": 0,
        "tx_count": 226,
        "created_at": "2021-04-08 17:40:00",
        "measurement": {
            "acceleration": "3820,64472,13188"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "pi_id": 0,
        "rcv_counter": 144,
        "rcv_RSSI": -64,
        "rcv_snr": 6.25,
        "packet_length": 131,
        "tag_id": 1,
        "cmd_id": 1,
        "tx_count": 108,
        "created_at": "2021-04-08 17:45:00",
        "measurement": {
            "location": "47.649755,9.481231"
        }
    }
```

How do I get all `measurement_types` per `id` into the my JSON structure?

Comment: Because you define your output like this: `$output[$resulthead['id']]` - meaning you overwrite the previous entry whenever an ID occurs more than once.

Comment: How would I need to define it to not overwrite it?

Comment: You would have to check if your output already contains a key equal to the ID of the current row. If not, add a whole new element to output. If yes, then just add the measurement type to the existing one.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thank you for your reply. I think I solved it with your hint. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the hint from @El_Vanja:

```
while ($resulthead = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if (isset($output[$resulthead['id']])) {
            switch ($resulthead['measurement_type']) {
                case 0:
                    $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['voltage'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['acceleration'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['location'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                    break; 
            } 


        } else {
       
            $output[$resulthead['id']] = [
                'id' => $resulthead["id"],
                'pi_id' => $resulthead["pi_id"],
                'rcv_counter' => $resulthead["rcv_counter"],
                'rcv_RSSI' => $resulthead["rcv_RSSI"],
                'rcv_snr' => $resulthead["rcv_snr"],
                'packet_length' => $resulthead["packet_length"],
                'tag_id' => $resulthead["tag_id"],
                'cmd_id' => $resulthead["cmd_id"],
                'tx_count' => $resulthead["tx_count"],
                'created_at' => $resulthead['created_at'] 
            ];
          
                switch ($resulthead['measurement_type']) {
                    case 0:
                        $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['voltage'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['acceleration'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $output[$resulthead['id']]['measurement']['location'] = $resulthead['measurement'];
                        break; 
                } 
    }}
```